# Page with a lot of content slowing down jQuery effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with dynamic content which has around 1600 lines on the `<body>`, and on the CSS a lot of images (I'm using CSS sprites and only using image where it's really necessary). But I still need to use jQuery UI effects and `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`.

But when I use those effects, they run very slow. Not slow like `.fadeIn('slow')`, but slow like breaking, like it's not normal... they don't look like the demo on jQuery website.

So, I assumed that was the large content of the page and images, so I made a test: run the page with just the header and the menu (where the jquery effects are running). With that, there was only a few images and only a few html elements and the effects run fine.

But I can't remove all the content and leave just that, I need the effect to run smoothly like it did with nothing there. Is there a way to do that? How?

Comment: Can you put a link to the page or a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)**?

Comment: read up on `lazy load content`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/